# In BigQuery, is there any way to see all queries across all users?

Tags: google-bigquery

Currently my role is owner, but I'm not seeing a way to view all queries across all users. I'm mainly interested in seeing bytes processed for each successful query. Without this ability, it makes it really hard to determine where the costs are coming from without asking each user individually. Is there a way to do this through the UI or the CLI command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Danny Kitt's answer got me part of the way there. Here's one of the Ruby scripts I wrote that ultimately gave me what I wanted. Should be easy enough to port to the language of your choice.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "json"
require "time"

MAX_RESULTS = 1000

jobs_json = `bq ls --format json --jobs --all --max_results #{MAX_RESULTS}`
jobs = JSON.parse(jobs_json)

users = {}
jobs.each do |job|
    if job["Job Type"] == "query" and job["State"] == "SUCCESS"
        job_data_json = `bq show --format=json --job #{job["jobId"]}`
    job_data = JSON.parse(job_data_json)
    creation_time = Time.at(job_data["statistics"]["creationTime"][0..-4].to_i)
    user = job_data["user_email"]
    bytes_processed = job_data["statistics"]["totalBytesProcessed"].to_i
    if bytes_processed > 0
      users[user] = 0 unless users.key?(user)
      users[user] += bytes_processed
      puts "[#{creation_time}] #{user}: #{bytes_processed} (running total: #{users[user]})"
      # puts job_data["configuration"]["query"]["query"]
    end
    end
end

puts "\nFINAL:\n"

users.each do |user, bytes_processed|
  puts "#{user}: #{bytes_processed}"
end
```

Answer (score 5):

In the CLI, you can run `bq ls -j -a` to retrieve jobs for all users in a project.  I don't think this command returns the bytes processed for a successful query, but a `bq show` on the successful queries' job IDs would retrieve the relevant information.

Using the API directly, you can specify the [`allUsers`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list#allUsers) parameter to a `jobs.list` request.

There is no way to view this information in the web UI at present.

Comment: Is it possible to see which user executed the query?

Comment: Yes, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993782/how-retrieve-the-user-and-sql-code-associated-with-a-bigquery-job/30995665#30995665

Answer (score 0):

[image: BigQuery UI]

The right corner of BigQuery UI, you can see a checkbox for `Show queries for all users`.

Comment: The  right checkbox is showing queries for all users but only for today , is it possible to retrieve it for a month or a year  ?