# Check who deleted some data from a specific table

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to check which user deleted some data from a specific table in BigQuery, is there anyway to do that? And is there a way to recover it?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I try to look for all the run jobs with the solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993782/how-retrieve-the-user-and-sql-code-associated-with-a-bigquery-job/30995665#30995665
But only showed some results, and not the complete list.

Comment: I think the audit logs as suggested by Mikhail would be the best approach indeed. I'm just not sure if it works just with data after it has been activated which means it can't log previous data from activation date. If this turns out to be the case for you then maybe asking for project owner to list all jobs will retrieve the complete list of actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to recover it?

you can use [`snapshot decorator`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators) to copy that table' data for specific point in a time into new table

> check which user deleted some data from a specific table in BigQuery

You can leverage Cloud Logging to filter your audit logs to find specific jobs that match your criteria, whether it’s expensive queries, specific failure modes, or unintended access patterns. See more here - [`Audit Logs`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs)

Comment: Thank you, @Mikhail. I found it in the audit logs. But I can't recover the table, since the job deleted the table and recriate a new one. The log says that I can only use the snapshot after the new table creation.